# How to open the same notebook with different kernels

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, jupyter, jupyterhub

Is there a possibility to open the same notebook multiple times but each time with another kernel?
I have a problem where I open and run a notebook and whilst I do some calculations another user opens the same notebook. Changes to variables I made will have an effect on that users output and vice versa.

Is there a way to stop this from happening (eg. can you configure a notebook so that it always opens a new kernel?)

Comment: Have you found a solution to this? Currently facing the same issue

Comment: I used a jupyterhub server with different users. Then when a user opens the notebook he gets a personal kernel